# Identify a QUIC Packet in UDP Payload

Tags: network-programming, udp, quic

I am trying to write a custom code that processes QUIC Initial packets. In a pcap file, I would like to identify quic packet from other UDP packets. I am not sure on which particular bit/ byte in the payload to look for.

[image: An Example]

The payload directly seems to start with quic headers. How to distinguish this from other UDP payloads like DNS, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no bit or field in the UDP header providing you information about the type of payload. You were probably searching for something like the `Protocol` field in the IPv4 header.

Wireshark uses so-called dissectors to determine the type of payload. You can find the QUIC dissector [here](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-quic.c).
Wireshark uses multiple techniques to determine if a UDP datagram contains QUIC payload. Some of them are:

- is the port used 80 or 443? If yes, the payload could be QUIC.
- is the beginning of the payload a valid QUIC header? This includes the verification of the QUIC version or the validation of the CID.

If you try to implement a simple dissector on your own, I would probably use the "easy" properties mentioned above.

I hope this does answer your question.